# react-query - How can I access my queries in multiple components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm just beginning with react query and used it to get a list of books from the server using useQuery in  my ListBooks Component

```
const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useQuery("books", getAllBooks);
```

How can I access the list of books in any other component?

I've setted the QueryClientProvider like so :

```
 const queryCache = new QueryCache({
  onError: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  },
});

const queryClient = new QueryClient({ queryCache });

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={preset}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm searching for the equivalent of useSelector in Redux to access the data in the redux store.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`react-query` manages query caching based on [query keys](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys), so in the other component, as long as they're all wrapped inside `QueryClientProvider`, you just need to call `useQuery` with the matching key (`books`), and `react-query` will return the appropriate data for you.

If you use the same query in multiple places, consider adding a wrapper hook to keep your code clean:

```js
function useAllBooks() {
  return useQuery("books", getAllBooks)
}
```

```js
function Component1() {
  const {...} = useAllBooks()
  return (...)
}

function Component2() {
  const {...} = useAllBooks()
  return (...)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response @NearHuscarl, so there isn't a "store" in react-query accessible from anywhere like in redux ?

Comment: By store, do you mean all cache data? @medfouedslama

Comment: @medfouedslama you can use `queryClient.getQueryCache().queries`. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/67091583how-can-i-access-my-queries-from-react-query-zw7iz?file=/src/App.js) example.

Comment: thank you, that's what i was looking for.

Comment: please note that accessing the cache imperatively via the queryClient does NOT create a subscription, so your component will not be re-rendered if you use this during the render function, and it will also not trigger a fetch if the cache is empty. Only `useQuery` does that, so I'd recommend to always `useQuery` to read data from the cache.

Answer (score 11):

You can get access with custom hook `useGetFetchQuery` and [useQueryClient](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/reference/useQueryClient)

```
import { useQueryClient } from "react-query";

export const useGetFetchQuery = (key) => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    return queryClient.getQueryData(key);
};
```

And in component just write like this

```
const data = useGetFetchQuery("key from useQuery or useMutation");
```

##### UPD

As correctly note *@Tony Tai Nguyen* with new (v5) release of `react-query` query keys should be an [**array**](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/guides/query-keys).

```
const data = useGetFetchQuery(["query key"]);
```

Comment: This is the cleaniest approach to reach for allready fetched 'data'. But the variable 'data' is not reactive - That means that if the data is refetched/updated and so on - the 'data' variable will not update/ be updated... :(

Is there a way to subscribe to data from a specific query?

Comment: this is returning undefined for me.

Comment: This function (useGetFetchQuery) will not update when query gets invalidated or udpated.

Comment: Note: if you are using the latest version of react query v5, you have to wrap the key around an array `queryClient.getQueryData([key]);`