# Using a value from a previous query in react query

Tags: javascript, react-query

I have a react query to get user data like this

```
const { data: queryInfo, status: queryInfoLoading } = useQuery('users', () =>
    getUsers()),
  );
```

I then have a sibling component that needs the same data from the get users query. Is there a way to get the results of the get users query without re-running the query?

Essentially, I would like to do something like this

```
const userResults = dataFromUserQuery

const { data: newInfo, status: newInfoLoading } = useQuery('newUserData', () =>
        getNewUsers(userResults.name)),
      )
```

Comment: How about `setState(...)\useState(...)` to reference the data?

Comment: I wanted to do that but it's not a parent child relationship so I can't pass it down

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67091583/9449426)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in this related question ([how can i access my queries from react-query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091583/how-can-i-access-my-queries-from-react-query)), writing a custom hook and reusing it wherever you need the data is the recommended approach.

Per default, react-query will trigger a background refetch when a new subscriber mounts to keep the data in the cache up-to-date. You can set a `staleTime` on the query to tell the library how long some data is considered fresh. In that time, the data will always come from the cache if it exists and no refreshes will be triggered.