# What is the proper way to get the earlier fetched result

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I've started to learn `react-query` and can't find a way to retrieve fetched data from another component by query key.

For instance, a top hierarchy component is fetching data:

```
const { data: chapters } = useQuery(
    'chapters',
    getChapters,
  );
```

Now I want to use chapters somewhere else, I don't want to re-fetch it. ( I know it's cached) I need to get a result only. Something like:

```
// const chapters = useQueryResult('chapters');
```

If I do:

```
const { data: chapters } = useQuery('chapters');
```

it of course refreshes data with empty result.

Is it really not possible to get just a result, so everywhere I need chapters I must use `useQuery` with a fetch function?

```
     ...

     useQuery(
        'chapters',
        getChapters,
      );
```

I see only a way to create a custom hook and use it everywhere I need...

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67091583

Comment: It seems to me yes..  they suggest the approach i've described. like create a custom hook. Thanks

Comment: Writing a custom hook that composes of other hooks to remove repetitive logic is one of the reasons hook exists in the first place. I believe it's the best solution for you.